# Animation Drawable + Android + Start and stop animation

Tags: java, android, multithreading, animation

I am creating an application that implements an animation, when a certain variable is true, when I start the activity and the variable is true, the animation works, but if I change the variable, and then change it back to the true variable the animation will not work. Does anybody have any ideas as to why?

Declare Variables

```
// Load the ImageView that will host the animation and
         // set its background to our AnimationDrawable XML resource.
         chargeStatus = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.chargeStatus);
        chargeStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chargeon);

         // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
         chargeAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) chargeStatus.getBackground();
```

Starts the thread on app start

```
 /////When Application Starts
@Override
public void onStart() 
{
    super.onStart();

    Thread cThread = new Thread(new serverThread()); //Starts the thread that initiates     communications
    cThread.start();
```

Thread That sets the value

```
public class serverThread implements Runnable 
{
    //public boolean connected = false; //connection
    public void run() //runs the thread
    {

        try 
        {
            functions.connectToServer(serverIp); //connects to server
            connected = true;

            while (connected) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    connectStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_car);
                    functions.getStreams(); //establish stream connections
                    functions. updateStatus(); //updates the status of the server
                    changeButtonImage(); //sets initial state for charge button



                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(2500);
                    }
                          catch ( InterruptedException interruptedException ) 
                          {
                             functions.displayMessage( "\nThread exception" );
                          } // end catch

                }
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        Log.e("Client","Trouble Getting Streams",e);


                    }



            }//end while
        }//end try
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Client", "Error Connecting", e);
                connected = false;
                connectStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_car);

            }
    }; //end run
}; //end serverThread
```

Change button function

```
public void changeButtonImage(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){


        public void run() {


            if (functions.chargeStatNumber != 0) 
            {
                // Start the charge animation 
                 chargeAnimation.start();
                //set the Charge on off button to stop
                chargeOnOff.setImageResource(R.drawable.charge_off);

            }
            else 
            {
                // stop the charge animation if running
                 chargeAnimation.stop();
                //set charge on off button to on
                chargeOnOff.setImageResource(R.drawable.charge_on);
                //set the charging symbol to off
                chargeStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_charging);
            }
        }});
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help you.Give name to images incrementaly(image1,image2,image3...).

```
public class DemoAnimation extends Activity {
    private boolean reverseOrder = false;
    private int imageIndex = 0;
    AnimationThread animThread;
    ImageView imgdone;
    public void onCreate(Bundle instance) {
        super.onCreate(instance);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        imgdone=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        if (animThread == null) {
            animThread = new AnimationThread();
            animThread.start();
    }
    }
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            try {
                imgdone.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image
                        + message.arg1);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    private class AnimationThread extends Thread {
        boolean _startAnimation = true;

        public void run() {

            while (_startAnimation) {

                Message message = new Message();
                if (!reverseOrder) {

                    if (imageIndex >= 5)
                        reverseOrder = true;

                    message.arg1 = imageIndex;
                    if (imageIndex < 5)
                        imageIndex++;
                    else if (imageIndex == 5)
                        imageIndex--;

                } else {

                    if (imageIndex <= 0)
                        reverseOrder = false;
                    message.arg1 = imageIndex;
                    if (imageIndex > 0)
                        imageIndex--;
                    else if (imageIndex == 0)
                        imageIndex++;

                }
                handler.sendMessage(message);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

//to stop thread

```
if (animThread != null)
    animThread._startAnimation = false;
```

Comment: deleted, sorry it was a dumb question.

Comment: I have been looking and trying to figure it out, but how did you make it where you can change the image numbers, and just leave the first part of the name blank?  imgdone.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image
                        + message.arg1);
I get an error message that the piture does not exist, and the .arg1 gives me an error, though I have imported the Android Message methods.

Comment: Is there a way I can message you? I would rather not put my email openly on the net.

Comment: drop me an email @ hitendrasinh87@gmail.com.I am using this email id for google-android groups.so I dont have any problem to share it.

Comment: I was changing the animation picture to another if a certain state is reached, and I found out that if I do that, I can not change  the imageview back to the animation, so not I just leave the animation, as it is and stop it, and my animation works, and I can start and stop it, thank you for your help.

Comment: I was wrong, all I had to do was re-declare the imageview as null, and then declare the animation before the.start() method, and it works perfectly now.